# how to access a class through id using jquery?

Tags: jquery, class, fieldset

I have an html as follows:

`<fieldset id="question1"> 
  <legend class='legend'>...</legend>`

`...`

`<input type="text" name="label_no1" id="label_no1" autocomplete="off">`

`</fieldset>`

On the java script, I'm cloning the fieldset, yet I want to access its element to change ids, and some of the text.

I tried this and it did not work:

`$('#question1").siblings(".legend").html="any text"; \\ I also tried children`

I also want to be able to access all the inputs inside the fieldset, so to change their ids.
Any help?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. Why are you cloning the fieldset - do you want to insert it someplace else? And what do you need to change inside the cloned fieldset?

Comment: For the part of how to access class through id, I got working answers,thank you all for you quick response.

Yet I still need help on how to access the inputs found on the field set, do I have to add class to each input and then change its id using the attr method?

Comment: Yes, you have to change the IDs on the inputs, but no, you don't need to put a class on them to do that. I've updated my answer to show how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the fieldset and add it to the same parent:

```
var fieldset = $("#question1");    // Get the fieldset
var clone = fieldset.clone();      // Clone it
clone.attr("id", "question2");     // Set its ID to "question2"
clone.appendTo(fieldset.parent()); // Add to the parent
```

Note we're [changing](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) the ID before adding it to the tree, since you can't have two elements with the same ID.

To do things with the elements within it, you can use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on your `clone` variable with a selector to select the children/descendants you want (once you've added the clone to the parent). For instance, to clean up the `id`s on the inputs:

```
clone.find('input').each(function() {
    if (this.id) {
        // It has an ID, which means the original had an ID, which
        // means your DOM tree is temporarily invalid; fix the ID
        this.id = /* ...derive a new, unique ID here... */;
    }
});
```

Note that within the `each` callback, `this` is *not* a jQuery instance, it's the raw element. (Hence my setting `this.id` directly.) If you wanted to get a jQuery instance for the element, you'd do `var $this = $(this);` and then use `$this.attr("id", ...)` instead. But there's no particular need unless you're doing something other than changing the ID.

---

Answering your question about renumbering IDs, you'll need to be sure you update whatever's *using* those IDs as well as the actual IDs on the input elements.

But in terms of doing the update on the input elements, you *could* do it by reading the number and incrementing it until you get one that isn't used:

```
clone.find('input').each(function() {
    var id;
    if (this.id) {
        id = this.id;
        do {
            id = id.replace(/[0-9]+$/g, function(num) {
                return String(Number(num) + 1);
            });
        }
        while ($("#" + id).length > 0);
        this.id = id;
    }
});
```

...which will give you "input_radio2" if the original ID was "input_radio1", but I think I'd probably use a different naming convention instead. For instance, you could prefix your various input IDs with the ID of the question:

```
<fieldset id='question1'>
    ...
    <input id=-'question1:input_radio1' />
</fieldset>
```

...and then just replace 'question1' with 'question2' in the cloned IDs. (Colons [`:`] are perfectly valid in IDs.)

If you can avoid having IDs on all of your inputs, though, that would be the way to go. For instance, unless your markup prevents it for a different reason, you can associate an `input` with its `label` via containment rather than using `for`:

```
<label>First name: <input type='text' ... /></label>
```

Lots of options. :-)

Comment: @zeina: LOL, I was just answering your earlier question when you posted that. My solution is similar, but guards against conflicts. But I think it might be worth taking a step back and refactoring the form a bit (he says, not knowing anything about the requirements!). :-)

Comment: Thanks very much. One last question, if I want to remove cloning, how I can do that? Just set it to hidden? I doubt that there is a better way.

Comment: @zeina: You mean, if you want to remove the clone at some point? Just call `$("#idOfClone").remove()`: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Thanks, you taught me much new stuff on jquery today. thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the id of the question using the **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method:

```
var q2 = $('#question1').clone();
q2.attr('id', 'question2');
```

To edit specific children in your new element, you want the **[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** method:

```
var legend = q2.find('.legend').html('....');
```

Comment: Thanks Dexter, your method worked. Now if I want to change an id of an input that is inside the fieldset, do you know how to do it? Note that I have many inputs inside it.

Comment: a little typo: `$('#question1").clone();` should be `$('#question1').clone();` you closed a single quoted string with a double quote

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$clone = $('#question1').clone();

$clone.attr('id','some_new_id');
// you don't need to search by class or id you can search for tags also,
// so you can get rid of some redundancy and write <legend>…</legend>
// instead of <legen class="legend">…</legend>
// siblings won't work with your example, because legend is a child not a sibling
// html= won't work either html on a jQuery object is a method not an attribute
$clone.find('legend').html("New text for the Legend");
```

Comment: @zeina: If the contents of the fieldset have `id` s, though, you *will* need to clean those up unless they're being replaced because they're inside the `legend` elements. The HTML snippet in your question has them outside the `legend` elements (and they have `id` s), so this won't quite do it though it'll get you close.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `html` method has a syntax as follows:

```
var result = $(selector).html(); // result now contains the html of the first matched element

@(selector).html('some html markup'); // the html of all matched elements are set to 'some html markup'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the class using this id.

```
document.querySelector('#player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active');
document.querySelector('#player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');
```